# Flutter Cubit: why does my state keep returning to initial state?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, bloc, cubit

I'm trying to use bloc pattern (with cubits) to manage tha state of my application. Everything is ok when I start my app: the state changes from initial state (i.e. RecipesInitial) to the RecipesLoaded state due to fetch the data from my file storage. The problem starts when I move to the NewRecipe page (for adding a new recipe), I fill in the form, I click on "Crea" button and then, after terminating the operation, it comes back to the HomePage (adding a new recipe works fine: after the operation, I can find the new file in my local storage), but the HomePage doesn't update.
Doing some debug prints, I have found that the HomePage state is RecipeInitial and it doesn't move to RecipesLoaded anymore.

More precisely, these are my files.

**HOME PAGE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/bloc/recipes_cubit.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/view/widgets/card_list.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BlocProvider.of<RecipesCubit>(context).fetchRecipes();

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/new"),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
        toolbarHeight: 150,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: const Text(
          'Ricettario',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: "Martian Mono"),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/search"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<RecipesCubit, RecipesState>(builder: (context, state) {
        debugPrint(state.toString());
        if (state is! RecipesLoaded) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        final tags = (state).tags;
        final recipes = (state).recipes;

        debugPrint(recipes.toString());
        debugPrint("In HomePage $tags");

        return ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: tags.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
            // Here you just have the list of recipe which makes use of tags and recipes variables
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, at the beginning of build method, I fetch the data. While, in the body, if the the state isn't RecipesLoaded, I show a progress indicator.
This works fine when I first start the application, namely the application starts, shows the indicator and after that it show the list of recipes.
Now the NewRecipe page:

**NEW RECIPE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/bloc/add/add_recipe_cubit.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/bloc/recipes_cubit.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/utilities/converters.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/utilities/validators.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/view/widgets/error_dialog.dart';

class NewRecipe extends StatelessWidget {
  NewRecipe({super.key, this.modify = false, this.toEditRecipe});

  final bool? modify;
  final Recipe? toEditRecipe;
  
  //HERE THE LIST OF CONTROLLER

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
        toolbarHeight: 150,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: const Text(
          'Crea una nuova ricetta',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
              fontSize: 19,
              fontFamily: "Martian Mono"),
        ),
      ),
      body: BlocListener<AddRecipeCubit, AddRecipeState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is RecipeAdded) {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          } else if (state is AddRecipeError) {
            showErrorDialog(context, "Ops! Qualcosa è andato storto",
                "Sembra che una ricetta con lo stesso nome esista già", "Ok");
          }
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            // Here I just have a form with lots of fields

                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        Recipe recipe = Recipe(
                            Converters.parseString(_catController.text), //type
                            Converters.parseString(_nameController.text), //name
                            Converters.toTime(
                                _prepController.text), // preparation time
                            Converters.toTime(
                                _cookController.text), // cooking time
                            Converters.makeList(
                                _ingController.text), // ingredients
                            Converters.makeList(
                                _recipeController.text), // recipe instructions
                            _notesController.text, // notes
                            Converters.toTime(
                                _restController.text), // resting time
                            Converters.toTime(
                                _risController.text) // rising time
                            );

                        BlocProvider.of<AddRecipeCubit>(context)
                            .addRecipe(recipe);  // THIS WORKS FINE
                      }
                    }, child: BlocBuilder<AddRecipeCubit, AddRecipeState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        if (state is AddingRecipe) {
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                        return const Text('Crea');
                      },
                    )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also this works, namely the application creates a new recipe, it emits a **RecipeAdded** event and therefore it returns back to the home page.

**ADD RECIPE CUBIT**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/bloc/recipes_cubit.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/data/file_storage.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'add_recipe_state.dart';

class AddRecipeCubit extends Cubit<AddRecipeState> {
  final FileStorage storage;
  final RecipesCubit recipesCubit;

  AddRecipeCubit({required this.storage, required this.recipesCubit})
      : super(AddRecipeInitial());

  Future<void> addRecipe(Recipe recipe) async {
    emit(AddingRecipe());
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      storage.write(recipe).then((val) {
        if (val) {
          recipesCubit.addRecipe(recipe);
          emit(RecipeAdded());
        } else {
          emit(AddRecipeError(error: "Recipe already exists"));
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**ADD RECIPE STATE**

```
part of 'add_recipe_cubit.dart';

@immutable
abstract class AddRecipeState {}

class AddRecipeInitial extends AddRecipeState {}

class AddRecipeError extends AddRecipeState {
  final String error;

  AddRecipeError({this.error = ""});
}

class AddingRecipe extends AddRecipeState {}

class RecipeAdded extends AddRecipeState {}
```

**RECIPE CUBIT**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/data/file_storage.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:recipe_book/utilities/utilities.dart';

part 'recipes_state.dart';

class RecipesCubit extends Cubit<RecipesState> {
  final FileStorage storage;

  RecipesCubit({required this.storage}) : super(RecipesInitial());

  void fetchRecipes() {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      storage.getAll().then((recipes) {
        emit(RecipesLoaded(
            recipes: recipes, tags: Utility.getOrderedTagList(recipes)));
      });
    });
  }

  void updateRecipesList() {
    final currentState = state;
    if (currentState is RecipesLoaded) {
      emit(RecipesLoaded(
          recipes: currentState.recipes, tags: currentState.tags));
    }
  }

  addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
    debugPrint(state.toString()); //THIS PRINTS RecipesInitial
    final currentState = state;
    if (currentState is RecipesLoaded) {
      final recipeList = currentState.recipes;
      recipeList.add(recipe);
      emit(RecipesLoaded(
          recipes: recipeList, tags: Utility.getOrderedTagList(recipeList)));
    }
  }
}
```

**RECIPE STATE**

```
part of 'recipes_cubit.dart';

@immutable
abstract class RecipesState {}

class RecipesInitial extends RecipesState {}

class RecipesLoaded extends RecipesState {
  final List<Recipe> recipes;
  final List<String> tags;

  RecipesLoaded({this.recipes = const [], this.tags = const []});
}
```

Ok, so now when I fetch, I emit a RecipesLoaded, then I move to NewRecipe page, I add a new recipe and emit a RecipeAdded, I come back and the state is RecipesInitial. In fact, in **addRecipe** from **RecipesCubit** the state is **RecipesInitial**, therefore the application can't enter in the if statement, so it can't retrieve the recipes list from the state and I don't have the updated list.
My question, therefore, is: how can I keep the **RecipesLoaded** state throughout the running

Comment: can you just add this getOrderedTagList method implementation, I am creating a dummy example to see what is wrong.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

So from the code that you provided i did try to run it successfully.

Now why does it only show the RecipesInitial, so the answer to the this question lies in where you instantiate the cubits

Code 1

```
runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<RecipesCubit>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => RecipesCubit(storage: storage),
      ),
      BlocProvider<AddRecipeCubit>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => AddRecipeCubit(
            storage: storage, recipesCubit: RecipesCubit(storage: storage)),
      ),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(routes: {
      // You can also use MaterialApp's `home` property instead of '/'
      '/new': (_) => NewRecipe(), // No way to pass an argument to FooPage.
    }, home: const HomePage()),
  ));
```

Code 2

```
 runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<RecipesCubit>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => RecipesCubit(storage: storage),
      ),
      BlocProvider<AddRecipeCubit>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => AddRecipeCubit(
            storage: storage,
            recipesCubit: BlocProvider.of<RecipesCubit>(context)),
      ),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(routes: {
      // You can also use MaterialApp's `home` property instead of '/'
      '/new': (_) => NewRecipe(), // No way to pass an argument to FooPage.
    }, home: const HomePage()),
  ));
}
```

If you can see the above snippets over here i have instantiated the cubits on top so that they can be accessed all over the app.

Now closely look at the Code 1 Snippet, here the AddRecipeCubit cubit that i have created has a parameter(recipesCubit:) which i have directly created the instance.
And in Code 2 i have not created the instance I have just accessed the instance which is already created from above.

*Note: if you want to access the instance that is created, it should be created first and then it can be accessed.*

Conclusion : You are creating a new instance which is causing the issue.